# struct definition with ':' after name of the variable

Tags: c, struct

I'm reading about structs in C and I came across some interesting declaration that I don't know what does is mean. The declaration goes as follows:

```
typedef struct name{
   int x :1;
}name;
```

what does line 'int x :1;' mean ? is 1 the default value of x?

Would appreciate help! Thanks

Comment: Please don't add tags for multiple very different languages unless both are involved.

Comment: The term to look up is "bitfield". You can squeeze multiple members into same `int` member by specifying a bit size. Beware: They are implementation defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It specifies the number of bits to use for that field. It is called "bit field".

Check this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field